# Responsive CSS: Prevent a search bar and button from getting bigger when zoomed in?

Tags: css, responsive

I have created a responsive website about a year ago and took a Big Commerce theme and altered it to be my own. I have put a button next to a search bar in the header. To test responsiveness I zoom in and out to see what happens. When I do, the search bar and button seem to move around quite a bit and get bigger. I would like it to stay put like the header, bag button and phone number. Here is my code...

```css
/* CSS */
#SearchForm2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 3%;
    z-index: 52;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
#SearchForm2 form {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
#SearchForm2 label {
    display: none;
}
#SearchForm2 input {
    display: block;
    height: auto; 
    width: auto;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;
}
#SearchForm2 p {
    display: none;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#SearchForm2 input.Textbox {
    float: right;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 59%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: .5em 1em;           
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 17px;
    background-color: transparent; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.searchbtn2 {
    float: right;
    width: 39%;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 3px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: "Cabin", Arial, Sans-serif;
     *display: inline;
     *zoom:1;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 4px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    background-color: #454545;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #454545;
}
.searchbtn2:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header Search -->
<div id="SearchForm2">
  <form action="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/search.php" method="get" onsubmit="return check_small_search_form(this)">
  <label for="search_query">%%LNG_Search%%</label>
    
    <input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" class="Textbox autobox" value="%%LNG_Search%%" />

    <button type="submit" class="searchbtn2" name="Search" title="Search">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is a link to see it in action: https://www.luxuryeyesite.com/test3/

Comment: Do you actually "zoom" in or do you re-size your browser?  If you're using Chrome, have you tried Chrome's built-in device emulator? (F12, then ctrl+shift+M on Windows). Also, can you be a bit more specific about "move around quite a bit"? I see the bag icon shrinking and growing, is that what you're having your issue with?

Comment: I use mac so on firefox or safari I resize the browser with Command + or -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a percentage for your font size.  As inputs are zoomed into the percentages will also increase.  If you don't want this to occur you'll need to stop using a percentage on `#SearchForm2 input.Textbox` and `.searchbtn2`

Also, this isn't the way I would recommend testing responsiveness.  If you are using Chrome open the developer tools and select the 'toggle device toolbar' button to get a more accurate representation.

[image: Chrome developer tools]

Comment: Sorry, I should of mentioned this is for desktop only, not mobile. Does this change your answer?

Comment: @Rhino No, font size as a percentage is definitely the issue.  As you zoom, your content enlarges.  The font-size is set to be 100% in the available area.  As the available area enlarges so will the font.  Updating to something like `font-size:20px;` will fix the font size to one specific size and prevent it from enlarging no matter what you zoom into.  Obviously you will have to test and see what specific font-size will work best for your needs.

Comment: @Rhino, also, I mentioned the above method for debugging because zooming in and out on your browser does not accurately test anything.  If you are testing what your page will look like on smaller screens or different window sizes using above method or even resizing your own browser window will work better.  I noticed you said you use Firefox, well then have a similar mode called Responsive Design Mode you could try.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, looks great now! I have also been using ScreenFly for responsiveness. Are they accurate?

Comment: @Rhino I have never used screenfly but from what I see it should definitely give you better results than zooming in the browser.  Also, if this is the correct answer for you please mark it as correct, thanks!